# Arduino HttpClient getString issue with NULL characters. ESP32

Tags: arduino, httpclient, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, esp32

The response to my http.Get() method which is in hex supposed to look like 
0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x08,0xff
but when u try to collect the data using 
response = http.getString() ; 
i got empty string may be cause getString() terminate it by seeing 0x00 (NULL)

So is there any method to replace getString() or to receive unit8_t bytes in get method response

ps code work as it supose to if I edit the response to 0x04,0x08,0xff on server

Comment: http protocol is designed to communicate using entirely ascii visible code strings.  If you do not want to communicate using 'text' then do not use the http protocol.

Comment: @webmite Images are sent via HTTP protocol and they are binary.

Comment: @gre_gor only when properly encapsulated within the protocol. The question specifically says that they are trying to use the getString() function. Hence a 'String' is the expected datatype.

Comment: Just to clarify I get my binary values if they are not starting with null

Comment: What normally marks the end of a string?  Why wouldn't you expect a function named "getString" to end there?

Comment: @Delta_g most of the string function look for 0x00 or Null to terminate the string.
My server send information of 8 sensors in binary. So some time sensor might be off so it send 0x00 which string function act as termination of string

Answer (score 0):

Use http.getstream

```
WiFiClient * stream = http.getStreamPtr();
      while(http.connected() && (len > 0 || len == -1)) 
      {
      // get available data size
      size_t size = stream->available();
      if(size) {
       // read up to 128 byte
      int c = stream->readBytes(response, ((size > sizeof(response)) ? 
      sizeof(response) : size));
      if(len > 0) {
                  len -= c;
                  }
               }
       delay(1);
```

}